# How do I find an attribute in a JSON file that contains any letter of the alphabet using jq?

Tags: json, regex, jq, character-class

I have a JSON document I am querying for some data. I need to loop through the IDs and find any IDs that contain a letter. Currently I have:

```
cat results.json | jq '.array|map(select( (.id|contains("a")) or (.id|contains("b")) ))' etc. etc.
```

How can I write a more efficient query/regex to do this in one `contains()` function e.g. something like:

```
cat results.json | jq '.array|map(select( (.id|contains("a-z")) ))' etc. etc.
```

Thanks!

Comment: [`test`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#test(val),test(regex;flags)) checks against a regular expression.

Comment: Please post a sample of the `results.json` file.

Answer (score 4):

To check whether a string contains a letter of the alphabet, you could use `test("[A-Za-z]")`.

Consider also character classes, e.g.

```
test("\\p{Alpha}")
test("\\p{L}")
```

For safety, you’ll probably also want to select or check for strings, e.g. using the form:

```
select( .id | strings | test(...) )
```

Comment: Thanks - managed to get it with get it with `cat results.json | jq '.array|map(select( (.id|match("[A-Za-z]")) ))`

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
[
  10,
  false,
  "foo",
  12,
  true,
  "bar",
  ":)",
  "99",
  "a99"
]
```

The following JQ filter:

```
map(select(strings|test("\\p{alpha}")))
```

will produce the following output:

```
[
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "a99"
]
```